# Zivot and Andrew test plot

Tags: r

I want to make a plot of ur.za by using package urca, however it gives numerical values on x-axis instead of years, is there anyway to put years on x-axis.Here is the example from (urca) package.

```
library(urca)
data(nporg)
gnp <- na.omit(nporg[, "gnp.r"])
za.gnp <- ur.za(gnp, model="both", lag=2)
summary(za.gnp)
plot(za.gnp)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to modify the `plot` function in the package `urca` for objects of class `ur.za`. This function can be found using

```
findMethods(plot)
```

The function of interest is named `ur.za#missing` (position 9 in the list given by `findMethods(plot)`):

```
findMethods(plot)@names
findMethods(plot)@.Data[[9]]
```

Here is the function:

```
Method Definition:

function (x, y, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (x) 
    {
        oldpar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
        on.exit(par(oldpar))
        par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
        yvals <- sort(c(x@cval, x@tstats))
        n <- length(x@y)
        xvals <- pretty(1:n)
        plot.ts(x@tstats, main = "Zivot and Andrews Unit Root Test", 
            ylab = "t-statistics for lagged endogenous variable", 
            ylim = c(min(yvals), max(yvals)))
        abline(h = x@cval, col = c("red", "blue", "seagreen"))
        if (x@teststat < x@cval[3]) {
            abline(v = x@bpoint, col = "red", lty = 2)
        }
        mtext(paste("Model type:", x@model, sep = " "), side = 1, 
            line = 4)
        legend(x = n, y = max(yvals), c("1% c.v.", "2.5% c.v.", 
            "5% c.v."), col = c("red", "blue", "seagreen"), xjust = 1, 
            yjust = 1, lty = 1, horiz = TRUE, cex = 0.66, bty = "n")
    }
    .local(x, ...)
}
<environment: namespace:urca>

Signatures:
        x       y        
target  "ur.za" "missing"
defined "ur.za" "missing"
```

Here is a modified version of the `plot` function that should solve the problem:

```
plot.ur.za <- function (Time, x, ...) 
{
        oldpar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
        on.exit(par(oldpar))
        par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
        yvals <- sort(c(x@cval, x@tstats))
        #xvals <- pretty(1:n)
        plot.ts(Time, x@tstats, main = "Zivot and Andrews Unit Root Test", 
            ylab = "t-statistics for lagged endogenous variable", type="l",
            ylim = c(min(yvals), max(yvals)), xy.labels=F, xy.lines=T)
        abline(h = x@cval, col = c("red", "blue", "seagreen"))
        if (x@teststat < x@cval[3]) {
            abline(v = Time[x@bpoint], col = "red", lty = 2)
        }
        mtext(paste("Model type:", x@model, sep = " "), side = 1, 
            line = 4)
        n <- length(Time)
        legend(x = Time[n], y = max(yvals), c("1% c.v.", "2.5% c.v.", 
            "5% c.v."), col = c("red", "blue", "seagreen"), xjust = 1, 
            yjust = 1, lty = 1, horiz = TRUE, cex = 0.66, bty = "n")
}
```

and the code to generate the plot:

```
library(urca)
data(nporg)
gnp <- na.omit(nporg[, c("gnp.r","year")])
za.gnp <- ur.za(gnp$gnp.r, model="both", lag=2)
plot(za.gnp)

yrs <- gnp$year[-length(gnp$year)]
plot.ur.za(Time=yrs, x=za.gnp)
```

[image]

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Sure i will @Marco.

Comment: I couldn't get the vertical dotted line in the plot, as i posted here, http://rpubs.com/rizwan/zaur

Comment: @I tried to upvote but don't have sufficient reputation