# Zivot and Andrew test plot in R

Tags: r

I performed the Zivot Andrew Unit Root test in R and I tried to plot the results, using the code of @Marco Sandri ([Zivot and Andrew test plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479318/zivot-and-andrew-test-plot))
However, instead of dates, I still get number on the horizontal axis. I think the issue is that if you enter dates in the format "%d%m%Y" you get numbers, instead of dates on the x axis.

To check the consistency of my results, I entered dates in the above format, using the dataset of @Marco Sandri as follows:

```
plot.ur.za <- function (Time, x, ...) 
{
    oldpar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
    on.exit(par(oldpar))
    par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
    yvals <- sort(c(x@cval, x@tstats))
    #xvals <- pretty(1:n)
    plot.ts(Time, x@tstats, main = "Zivot and Andrews Unit Root Test", 
        ylab = "t-statistics for lagged endogenous variable", type="l",
        ylim = c(min(yvals), max(yvals)), xy.labels=F, xy.lines=T)
    abline(h = x@cval, col = c("red", "blue", "seagreen"))
    if (x@teststat < x@cval[3]) {
        abline(v = Time[x@bpoint], col = "red", lty = 2)
    }
    mtext(paste("Model type:", x@model, sep = " "), side = 1, 
        line = 4)
    n <- length(Time)
    legend(x = Time[n], y = max(yvals), c("1% c.v.", "2.5% c.v.", 
        "5% c.v."), col = c("red", "blue", "seagreen"), xjust = 1, 
        yjust = 1, lty = 1, horiz = TRUE, cex = 0.66, bty = "n")
}
```

and thereafter, the following code to generate the post:

```
library(urca)
data(nporg)
dates <- seq(as.Date("01/01/1997", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), by = "months", length =     
length(nporg$cpi))
nporg$dates<-dates
gnp <- na.omit(nporg[, c("gnp.r","dates")])
za.gnp <- ur.za(gnp$gnp.r, model="both", lag=2)
plot(za.gnp)
yrs <- gnp$dates[-length(gnp$dates)]
plot.ur.za(Time=yrs, x=za.gnp)
```

You may find attached the results I got.
The question is the following: How can I plot the ZA test with dates in the horizontal axis using the "dates" variable I have created above?

[ZA plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV2MU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify `plot.ts()` function inside `plot.ur.za()` like:

```r
plot.ur.za <- function (Time, x, ...) 
{
  oldpar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
  on.exit(par(oldpar))
  par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
  yvals <- sort(c(x@cval, x@tstats))
  xvals <- pretty(1:length(Time))
  plot.ts(Time, x@tstats, main = "Zivot and Andrews Unit Root Test", 
          ylab = "t-statistics for lagged endogenous variable", type="l",
          ylim = c(min(yvals), max(yvals)), xy.labels=F, xy.lines=T,
          xaxt = "n")
  pl <- pretty(1:length(Time))
  axis(1,
       at = na.exclude(Time[pl]),
       labels = c(as.character(na.exclude(Time[pl]))),
       lwd.ticks = 1,
       lwd = 0)
  
  abline(h = x@cval, col = c("red", "blue", "seagreen"))
  if (x@teststat < x@cval[3]) {
    abline(v = Time[x@bpoint], col = "red", lty = 2)
  }
  mtext(paste("Model type:", x@model, sep = " "), side = 1, 
        line = 4)
  n <- length(Time)
  legend(x = Time[n], y = max(yvals), c("1% c.v.", "2.5% c.v.", 
                                        "5% c.v."), col = c("red", "blue", "seagreen"), xjust = 1, 
         yjust = 1, lty = 1, horiz = TRUE, cex = 0.66, bty = "n")
}
```

I have removed default `X` axis and provided new one with `axis()` function:

```r
library(urca)
data(nporg)
dates <- seq(as.Date("01/01/1997", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), by = "months", length =     
               length(nporg$cpi))
nporg$dates<-dates
gnp <- na.omit(nporg[, c("gnp.r","dates")])
za.gnp <- ur.za(gnp$gnp.r, model="both", lag=2)
plot(za.gnp)
```

[image]

```r
yrs <- gnp$dates[-length(gnp$dates)]
plot.ur.za(Time=yrs, x=za.gnp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-21 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Than you so much for your prompt response. It works.